# Chrome Dev Tools produces white line while docked to right. Can you get rid of it?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

While having dev tools docked to the right, there's a 3px wide white line on the side of it. I spent an hour looking for an error in my CSS because I thought it was a padding / margin issue somewhere but found it was always there, no matter what website I was browsing. Anyone know if there's a way to get rid of it?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGcH6.png

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents, you don't get rid of it, so if it bugs you that much, then, first sleep on it, think about it in the morning, after you aren't so annoyed about the wasted hour :)

Or Undock the Dev Tool window, as a separate window.

The 3px border is part of the UI, without it you cant resize the plugin window, no?

Comment: It has annoyed me for weeks. The gray 1px border should be enough to resize, or just have the extra 3px border on the right side for a bigger hit area. When the tools are docked to the bottom, there's no extra border. Why have it there on the side?

Currently it looks like a part of the web page, which I find very odd.

Comment: I agree with you (except about 1px being enough, my eyes are getting worse by the year), but I think you are better off submitting a feature request / bug report to the author(s) of the plugin. Sometimes a small donation gets their attention.